# Access modal form updates database then calling form update does not

Tags: vba, ms-access, modal-dialog, ms-access-forms

In Access a header form needs an address associated with it.  The header form calls a modal address form.  On Save the modal address form will write the address ID to the header form's record source address ID then close.  Coming back to the calling header form should then list the related address ID after a requery, that is the FK link.  I am not getting the address form's address ID written to the header form's record source address ID field and thus not listing on requery.  A fair amount of this code is based on several SO questions.
The header form calls a wrapper function to manage the modal address form:

```
Private Sub txtJob_AfterUpdate()
    
    gbolDropShipAddressCompleted = False
    
    'Use global variables for use in frmDropShipAddress SQL update statement
    gtxtCurrentJobNumber = Me.Job
    gtxtCurrentJobRelease = Me.REL
    gtxtCurrentJob = Me.txtJob
    
    'Call the wrapper function
    gbolDropShipAddressCompleted = fNewDropShipAddressCompletion()
        
    If gbolDropShipAddressCompleted = True Then
        'Me.Dirty = False
        Me.Requery
        With Me.RecordsetClone
            .FindFirst "[Job] = '" & gtxtCurrentJobNumber & "' And [REL] = '" & gtxtCurrentJobRelease & "'"
            If Not .NoMatch Then
                If Me.Dirty Then
                    Me.Dirty = False
                End If
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
            End If
        End With
        'Reset all variables
        gbolDropShipAddressCompleted = False
        gtxtCurrentJobNumber = ""
        gtxtCurrentJobRelease = ""
        gtxtCurrentJob = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

The wrapper function:

```
Public Function fNewDropShipAddressCompletion() As Boolean

    'Manages call to frmDropShipAddress
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDropShipAddress", , , , , acDialog, "From frmPackingSlipHeader"
    fNewDropShipAddressCompletion = gbolfrmDropShipAddressTofrmPackingSlipHeader
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDropShipAddress"

End Function
```

The modal form's two events:

```
Private Sub btnSaveAddressInfo_Click()

    DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    'Update MAIN table with new address id using global variables
    CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE [MAIN] " & _
        " SET intADDRESS_ID = " & Me.txtAddress_ID & _
        " WHERE JOB = '" & gtxtCurrentJobNumber & "'" & _
            " AND REL = '" & gtxtCurrentJobRelease & "'"
    gbolfrmDropShipAddressTofrmPackingSlipHeader = True
    Me.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    gbolfrmDropShipAddressTofrmPackingSlipHeader = 0

    If Me.OpenArgs = "From frmPackingSlipHeader" Then
         DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    'Coded because TabCtlDatePicker opens all forms and openargs is NULL and causes all forms to be affected
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Exit Sub
'    Else
'        Me.PopUp = True
'        Me.Modal = True
'        Me.BorderStyle = 1
'        Me.NavigationButtons = False
'        Me.RecordSelectors = False
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
The Access front-end uses several tab controls to select between many different reports/date and or data pickers all sorted into tab control pages by topic.  The back-end is MS SQL server via linked tables.  The address form may be opened for generic viewing or called (modal).  I can't seem to get the correct VBA to get the address form's address ID written to the header's record source and the VBA to get the header to requery and return to the correct record.  Any help would be appreciated and TIA.
Tim

Comment: If intAddress_ID is a number type field, don't use apostrophe delimiters. acDialog suspends code execution on calling form until called form is closed. So why would you need to have `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDropShipAddress"` on the calling form? Have you step debugged?

Comment: @June7 - the apostrophe delimiters have been removed.  frmDropShipAddress has a command button titled SAVE and controlled by Private Sub btnSaveAddressInfo_Click() above.  When the save happens and Me.Requery or Form.Requery runs, the form is taken back to the first record.  I then try a GoToRecord to the new record but it is not found and the db at that point is out of sync and the record match is lost and the form is at the first record.  This also happens on frmPackingSlipHeader after the wrapper function returns control, the GoToRecord cannot find that recently updated record, no match.

Comment: @June7 - Yes, stepping through code.  It appears when the requery and GoToRecord on frmDropShipAddress fires, that frmPackingSlipHeader is advancing to the record number instead of frmDropShipAddress.

Comment: I just noticed a spelling error. Missing 'g' in: `If Me.OpenArgs = "From frmPackinSlipHeader" Then`. Are you using a combobox for selecting address record? Customary approach is to use NotInList event to add new lookup record 'on-the-fly' during data entry.

Comment: What is the RecordSource of frmPackingSlipHeader? Instead of running an UPDATE action, just set value of field on frmPackingSlipHeader.

Comment: @June7 Sorry, I did find the typo and updated my data but not here.  Fixed.  I'll try to add screenprints.  In frmPackingSlipHeader a double click on txtJobNumber (identifying pronouns removed thus the green top left corner) opens frmDropShipAddress.  Did I answer your question.  I think all the code used for this process is posted here

Comment: @June7 The RecordSource for frmPackingSlipHeader is a query.  Ah, that's where I'm going out of sync!

Comment: So how does one get the query to be re-queried?

Comment: Should not have to requery. As I said, instead of UPDATE just set value of field on calling form. Probably should not use query as RecordSource but since I don't know what it is, hard to say if this change will resolve issue.

Comment: @June7 - the called frmDropShipAddress has intADDRESS_ID as identity and autonumber.  As the drop ship address is created it is associated with intADDRESS_ID.  When the address entry is completed that same intADDRESS_ID needs to be written to frmPackinSlipHeader intADDRESS_ID to make the relationship.  frmPackingSlipHeader uses a query as recordsource because data from two related tables are in that form.  Upon returning to the calling form, without the update, that relation will not be made and it can't be done upon return as the relation is broken.  I'm sure I'm doing something out of order.

Comment: Still don't know what the query is. Maybe instead of INNER JOIN, try LEFT or RIGHT. Afraid cannot help further without viewing db. Perhaps should post to a forum that facilitates and encourages attaching files.

Comment: June7 - Still at it.  I changed tact from popup to subform. I can get the subform to track with the form on txtADDRESS_ID and even make the subform invisible when IsNull(txtJobNumber) and vice versa as I navigate through records.  On a new record, after detail and address are complete, qryMAIN_Master does not get requeried and the form seems to "lose" that new record.  How do I get the main form to requery qryMAIN_Master after a new record is committed?